# Running Spark on local machine with master = local[*] and invoking .collect method

Tags: apache-spark

I need some help in understanding this documentation on Spark website:

> Another common idiom is attempting to print out the elements of an RDD using rdd.foreach(println) or rdd.map(println). [1st category] On a single machine, this will generate the expected output and print all the RDD’s elements. [2nd category] However, in cluster mode, the output to stdout being called by the executors is now writing to the executor’s stdout instead...

I running spark locally (with local[*] inside Eclipse IDE) that connects to staging Cassandra (which is running on multiple nodes) falls in the first category or second?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In this context spark cluster and cassandra cluster are not related. "collect" send data from spark executor nodes to spark driver node. "collect" knows nothing about data source (i.e. cassandra)

Comment: When running in local mode, the executors run in the same JVM as the driver and you'll see all the output in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not submitting your code to a cluster, therefore your code is the first category

Comment: Even when I use local[*]? My laptop has 4 cores. So it should use all 4 cores meaning 4 executors/workers. Meaning it is a cluster. Isn't it?

Comment: No. A cluster means multiple machines. You executors and drivers are still on a "single machine" just like the documentation says